# Use .htaccess RewriteCond and RewriteRule to redirect file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to use a RewriteCond and RewriteRule pair to redirect visitors from

domain.com/Online_Statement_Instructions_(Owner).pdf

to

domain.com/?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=5.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Online_Statement_Instructions_\(Owner\)\.pdf$
RewriteRule (.*) /?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=5 [R=301,L]
```

However, I'm not sure that I'm escaping characters correctly, or even that the rule is written correctly. At any rate, the rules aren't working: When someone visits domain.com/Online_Statement_Instructions_(Owner).pdf they don't get taken to domain.com/?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=5

How do I get a RewriteCond and RewriteRule pair to redirect visitors from that file to that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your visitors are visiting this URL:

```
domain.com/Online_Statement_Instructions_(Owner).pdf
```

then this is not really a QUERY_STRING, it is `REQUEST_URI` and you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Online_Statement_Instructions_\(Owner\)\.pdf$ /?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=5 [R=302,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't seem to work. When I visit 
http://exampledomain.com/Online_Statement_Instructions_(Owner).pdf
I get a 404, instead of being redirected to exampledomain.com/?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=5. Why is this?

Comment: This rules works fine on my Apache. Do you have any rule before this rule? Make sure this is your very first rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: Just had to move it up to the top. Thanks for the help!